# SQL to get cumulative salaries of all employees till the current month

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Lets say we have Three employees in Employee_Info table:

| Emp_Name | Month | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| emp1 | 2021-01 | 10000 |
| emp1 | 2021-02 | 13000 |
| emp1 | 2021-03 | 10000 |
| emp2 | 2021-01 | 15000 |
| emp2 | 2021-02 | 15000 |
| emp2 | 2021-03 | 12000 |
| emp3 | 2021-01 | 20000 |
| emp3 | 2021-02 | 20000 |
| emp3 | 2021-03 | 13000 |

I have to write a select sql query with an output like this:

| Emp_Name | Month | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| emp1 | 2021-01 | 10000 |
| emp1 | 2021-02 | 13000 |
| emp1 | 2021-03 | 10000 |
| emp1 | 2021-03 | 33000 |
| emp2 | 2021-01 | 15000 |
| emp2 | 2021-02 | 15000 |
| emp2 | 2021-03 | 12000 |
| emp2 | 2021-03 | 42000 |
| emp3 | 2021-01 | 20000 |
| emp3 | 2021-02 | 20000 |
| emp3 | 2021-03 | 13000 |
| emp3 | 2021-03 | 53000 |

As you see the new row which should have the sum of all salaries for a particular employee.

Comment: I just can't think why this would be a useful query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest method is just to use `union all`:

```
select emp_name, month, salary
from t
union all
select emp_name, max(month), sum(salary)
from t
group by emp_name
order by emp_name, month, salary;
```

Note that if you want the cumulative salary on each row, then you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(salary) over (partition by emp_name order by month) as running_salary
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67c345c99a154a9fbdf39d6c81860b1d) is a db<>fiddle.